# Defining shorttoc and toc title style

Tags: table-of-contents, shorttoc

I've been working on a custom title presentation for my document for titles `\part{}`, `\chapter{}`, `\section{}` and `paragraph{}`. I also use the extension `shorttoc` to make a summary at the start of my document and then display the full table of content at the end of it.

My problem is both my shorttoc and my toc are not displayed like my other styles. I would like them to be displayed like a `\part{}` but I can't figure how to do it.

I've searched on the Internet and found something not similar but still with the same objective. The following code was proposed to help her solve her problem:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@cftmaketoctitle{\chapter*{\contentsname}}
\makeatother
```

I didn't find a working solution with this because the asker was using the tocloft extension and I'm using shorttoc and the normal `\tableofcontents`

I firstly replaced `\chapter*` by `\part*` because I would like to have my title as a `\part`.

Then I get trouble with `\@cftmaketoctitle`. I tried to compile my document with it but didn't notice any change. So I tried it by replacing it with `\@shorttableofcontents` and `\@cftshorttableofcontents` like this, without seeing any change:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@shorttableofcontents{\part*{\contentsname}}
\makeatother
```

I'm new at LaTeX programming and have trouble to understand this `\@`, I've understood that `\def` is the `TeX` equivalent of `\newcommand` in LaTeX but I struggle to go farther.

Can anyone of you help me to design my shorttoc and toc title as a part?

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Pour générer du faux texte}
\usepackage{shorttoc}% Gestion du sommaire
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}% Pour un document en français

% --------------------------------------------------
% Paramétrage des parties
% --------------------------------------------------
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[frame]
    {\null\vspace{.10\textheight}\normalfont}
    {\fillright
    \enspace PARTIE~\thepart\enspace}
    {8pt}
    {\huge\bfseries\filcenter\textsc}

\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{*0}{*5}

\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}


\begin{document}
    \part{Here is a part}
    \lipsum

    \shorttableofcontents{Sommaire}{1}

    \part*{Introduction}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
    \markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}
    \lipsum

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}

    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Generally spoken, all commands starting with `\@` or having a `@` are internal commands, not needed for a users who do not plan to write a new package or document class, and therefore, they are somehow hidden, not being usable in a real document. They can be made available using the `\makeatletter` command (very simplified just now). However those commands are called anyway, by using other, non `@`-commands.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I added a MWE. :)

Thank you for the information Christian Hupfer, I didn't know it.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is working. :)

Sorry for the errors in the MWE, I got a pdf file in output so i thought it was good. You can give the exact answer you put in your last comment so I can mark you as resolved if you want. :)

Comment: @Berhthun: If your are working with `hyperref` package, you will additionally need `\phantomsection` commands before `\addcontentsline` statements, to correct the link targets etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to the problem is to copy the `\titleformat{part}` and say `\titleformat{chapter}` with the appropiate changes. This will suffice, since `\tableofcontents` and `\shorttableofcontents` use a `\chapter*{}` command to write the `\contentsname` title.

However, this will set the style for usual `\chapter`s as well.

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Pour générer du faux texte}
\usepackage{shorttoc}% Gestion du sommaire
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}% Pour un document en français
\usepackage{biblatex} % Most probably for \printbibliography

% --------------------------------------------------
% Paramétrage des parties
% --------------------------------------------------
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[frame]
    {\null\vspace{.10\textheight}\normalfont}
    {\filright
    \enspace PARTIE~\thepart\enspace}
    {8pt}
    {\huge\bfseries\filcenter\textsc}

\titleclass{\chapter}{top}
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
    {\null\vspace{.10\textheight}\normalfont}
    {\filright
    \enspace Chapitre~\thechapter\enspace}
    {8pt}
    {\huge\bfseries\filcenter\textsc}



\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{*0}{*5}




\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}


\begin{document}
    \part{Here is a part}
    \lipsum

    \shorttableofcontents{Sommaire}{1}

    \part*{Introduction}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
    \markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}
    \lipsum

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}



    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Sorry for bad knowledge of French ;-)

### Screenshots

[image]
[image]